# Busybox wget strange behaviour

Tags: wget

I need some help with a really strange problem.

I use wget (busybox) to obtain the the IP address of some remote clients, to use it on a DNS (a sort of "homemade ddns"). Those clients run a script that every 5 mins calls

```
wget -O /dev/null "https://my_dns.org/poll.php?user=User_N&pwd=password_N"
```

Everything was fine, until I updated my http server to remove TLS1.0/TLS1.1

After updating: running the above command on the clients' console it still works OK, while running it automatically  (launching it from a script in /etc/init.d) I get this error:

```
Connecting to my_dns.org (www.xxx.yyy.zzz:443)
wget: error getting response: Connection reset by peer
```

...Any idea about why does this happen, and how to fix...?
(The shell on the clients runs as root...)

Thank you in advance for your help

Regards

Comment: Do you get further details when logging standard errors to some log file, i.e. using `-o mylogfile.txt`?  Also, in order to see if this is about your TLS certificates, you could try adding `--no-check-certificate` (just for testing purposes)

Comment: No further details, unfortunately... I'm using wget from BusyBox v1.23.1, and the above error is all I see from wget > log 2>&1. Nothing in the https server's log -neither in access.log nor in error.log- because the connection fails before GET, I guess. All I can see is that launching the "contact" (the above wget line) from client's console, it works fine; while launching EXACTLY the same command from the script... it fails. BUT... it began failing after quitting support to TLS1.0/TLS1.1 on http server. Anyway, again: wget is STILL working OK, when you run it from command line (console). Tnx.

Comment: I've found that different PATH value was the root cause of different wget behaviours.
A stupid issue... my fault :)

Comment: Good you found the cause, I guess the PATH is a common pitfall :-)

Comment: What is the correct PATH value supposed to be? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: I think that the correct PATH value can change, according to the environment.
In my scenario, it's:


PATH='/userfs/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin'



Regards